# Configure MassTransit in Modular Monolith

Tags: c#, masstransit

i want use MassTransit for send events between another modules, but i dont know how configure it.
Now i have one shared infrastructure and two CRUD modules with 2 layers basic architecture (API + Core).

How i can create endpoint to trade event between modules ? I dont want use next project for contracts, i want simulate situation with indepedence services, but in monolith.

But this not working, i have two ProductCreateEvent in two modules with attribute [EntityName("products")]. MassTransit use InMemory broker

I tried some code like this:

```
 services.AddMassTransit(o =>
        {
            o.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
            {
                var consumersAssemblies = GetModuleAssembliesWithConsumers();

                var consumerTypes = consumersAssemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces()
                        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConsumer<>))));
                
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"products_queue", re =>
                {
                    foreach (var consumerType in consumerTypes)
                    {
                        var name = consumerType.Name;
                        
                        re.Consumer(consumerType, x => Activator.CreateInstance(consumerType));
                        //re.ConfigureConsumer(context, consumerType);   
                    }
                        
                    re.Bind("products", ExchangeType.Topic);
                });
                
                /*foreach (var assembly in consumersAssemblies)
                {
                    var consumerTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces()
                            .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConsumer<>)));

                    var localContracts = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name.Equals(nameof(IContract))));
                    //.Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILocalContract)));

                    
                   
                }*/
                
                
            });
        });
```

In my opinion, my fault is incorrectly MassTransit settings and second module dont listen /products
I dont know how fix it

Comment: [Messages](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages) must be in the same namespace. You're over-complicating your project by not having shared contracts.